# Write OR statement simply in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have if statement with OR expression in it.

```
if (cow == cow1 || cow == cow2) {
  //do something
}
```

Is there a better way of writing this in a simpler way?
I imagine somemthing like

```
if (cow == cow1 || cow2) {
  //do something
}
```

but I guess this is not working.

Comment: Not possible in JS.

Comment: The very best way is to use `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: What exactly is even wrong with the original code?

Comment: @AndrewL It's valid JS, but it won't solve this problem.

Comment: @nicael: The variable names are ugly, the logic is pretty simple and straightforward.  So I guess the OP should change the variable names?  Either way, that's entirely opinion-based and not a topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @AndrewL — It's valid, but it means something completely different to `if (cow == cow1 || cow == cow2) {`

Comment: `[cow1, cow2].includes(cow)` or `[cow1, cow2].indexOf(cow) != -1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that doesn't work. Because of operator precedence, it's treated as:

```
if ((cow == cow1) || cow2))
```

This doesn't compare `cow` with `cow2` -- if the first comparison is false, it simply tests whether `cow2` is truthy or not.

To test for inclusion in a set, you can use an array and the `indexOf()` method:

```
if ([cow1, cow2].indexOf(cow) != -1)
```

Comment: `(cow == cow1 || cow2)` is not equal `(cow == (cow1 || cow2))`.

Comment: `==` binds more tightly than `||`.

Comment: Oops, what was I thinking? Updating the answer now.

Comment: As @xufox pointed out, `Array.prototype.includes` can also be used (but may need to be polyfilled).